# Generated links broken in Hugo/Blogdown when publishing to domain with subfolder

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

I am trying to use [Hugo Xmin](https://github.com/yihui/hugo-xmin) to create a static site. My site will be hosted in the gh-pages of my repository, therefore the final URL will look like:

```
https://myuser.github.io/myrepo/
```

**Note** At my current stage, I haven't modified any file in the example site that comes along with the theme, so basically the site I am deploying is the same exact in the original repository.

#### Problem I

In my `config.toml` I have set:

```
baseurl = "https://myuser.github.io/myrepo/"
```

Because with `baseurl = "/"` my links to the static CSS files in the `<head>` were not working and the site looked messy. By specifying the base url, CSS is loaded fine, but then top bar links are broken because this is what is generated:

```html
<li>
  <a href="/myproj/myproj/about/">About</a>
</li>
```

Why is the generated URL looking so odd? The repository name is duplicated.

#### Problem II

The theme example site, in `/content/_index.Rmarkdown` has a few links at the end:

```
You can also visit the list page of a single section, e.g., [posts](/post/), or [notes](/note/). See the [About](/about/) page for more info.
```

Those do not work in my case because the URL that is generated is:

```
<a href="/post/">posts</a>
```

Which will redirect the user to: `https://myuser.github.io/post/` which is wrong. Basically this theme does not work when the hosting domain has a subfolder. Or am I missing anything here?

---

#### Troubleshooting

By investigating a bit I can see the theme defines those links like the following:

```
<ul class="menu">
  {{ range .Site.Menus.main }}
  <li><a href="{{ .URL | relURL }}">{{ .Name }}</a></li>
  {{ end }}
</ul>
```

Function `relURL` is taking what comes after the hostname ans spitting it twice in the generated URL :(

Comment: I'm also struggling with wrongly generated urls for sites where baseURL is a domain with a subfolder, as you say.  I've noticed numerous posts like yours. I've raised an issue at the hugo GitHub repository https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/issues/7714.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior of `relURL` seems to have changed since a certain version of Hugo (I don't know which). Anyway, you can remove the leading slashes in those menu items, e.g., change

```
[[menu.main]]
    name = "About"
    url = "/about/"
```

to

```
[[menu.main]]
    name = "About"
    url = "about/"
```

Comment: I guess that will apply also to the links in markdown I mentioned in problem II right? I will try to change them from: `/post/` to `post/`

Comment: It works. Yes sure is odd that they changed the behavior like this... It is a breaking change. I will create a PR to your theme to fix the links :) Thanks man you are always so helpful!!!!!